# Riddle: Safety in numberS

Tags: riddle

My last one charged politically
aimed at those who show hypocrisy
if you want the bounty worthy of a Spartan
then hearken here and answer this jargon.

> I am the reasons why you burn
>   well after you're left in the end of your turn
>   a plethora of actions lead you here
>   under a septenary of hate and fear
>
> Situated here, desolate of fortitude
>   just moulded eyes and tunnels of feud
>   for an act of me is negligible advice
>   my existence defended by who surmise

No patronising statement here
no tarnishing or reputational smear
just read the lines and think it through
revive the fun in riddles anew.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is related to

> The Seven Deadly Sins

Reasoning:

> I am the reasons why you burn
>   well after your left in the end of your turn

Taking "burn" literally, these actions will send you to Hell. The end of your turn meaning once you are dead.

> a plethora of actions lead you here
>   under a septenary of hate and fear

There are many reasons (a plethora of actions) one might commit any of these transgressions, but most of the time hate and/or fear are involved, as any good Jedi would tell you. In addition, *septenary* directly links to *seven*.

> Situated here, desolate of fortitude
>   just molded eyes and tunnels of fued

"Desolate of fortitude" means you are lacking resilience, and cannot stop yourself from committing them. Molded eyes and tunnels of feud sounds like some depictions of Hell from the Renaissance era to me.

> for an act of me is negligible advice

I wouldn't advise someone to commit these acts.

> my existance defended by who surmise

The existence of "sin" at all is defended by religion, which is literally people who surmise (suppose something to be true [without confirming evidence](https://www.google.com/search?espv=2&q=define+surmise&oq=define+surmise&gs_l=serp.3..0l4j0i22i30l5.494274.496018.0.496155.14.14.0.0.0.0.132.1065.13j1.14.0.msedr...0...1c.1.58.serp..0.14.1064.pKWyOquOQFM)).

In addition, the title has a capital S at beginning at end instead of the usual title case: `Safety in numberS`, so the answer could be shortened to

> Seven Sins

Comment: congratulations give that man a sandwich.

Comment: apart from getting it spot on do you have any criticism?

Comment: Seriously. I'm starving over here. Just hold the mayo ;)

Comment: Nothing major. It seemed like the obvious answer to me, but I don't know how easy it would be for someone else. Things like burn/sept-/hate/fear just jumped out to me as big flags. Nicely written, though, with no big red herrings.

Comment: fair enough, just for confirmation the end of turn should resemble both the end of your life and the end of turn itself as in urn. molded eyes are such colours as green and black, green eyes are for envy. Tunnel is to resemble tunnel vision for wrath.

Comment: and nicely pointed out in the title, it fits in with seven sins aswell as it being an acronym for sin's which is why I capitalised the last letter also

Comment: Ah, I figured I was missing something with the eyes/tunnel part but couldn't put my finger on it. I never would have guessed the turn/urn connection, though (since it fit so nicely already with death, I didn't see it needing another reason to be there). And I totally missed the title being a complete acronym XD